# Prevent Circular References in Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, circular-reference

I have these tables :

--Location (ID)

--Concert (ID , LocationID_FK)

--Showtimes (ID , ConcertID_FK)

--SeatBlock (ID , ShowtimesID_FK)

--Seat (ID , SeatBlockID_FK)

Now i have an entity called SeatValue.this entity is a value for some seats,like Golden,Silver and so on.For this entity every records must have an specified Showtime.
I Think this is solution :

SeatValue (ID , ShowtimesID_FK)

and Seats changes to :

--Seat (ID , SeatBlockID_FK , SeatValueID_FK)

But i think it's create cicular reference.isn't it?
How can i change it?

Comment: Why not tie your seatvalue as a zero-or-one reference to the seat?

Comment: SeatValue has some records and it must be seprate than the Seat.it has name and price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, I would propose the following:

- Location (ID, metadata)
- Concert (ID , LocationID_FK, metadata)
- Showtimes (ID , ConcertID_FK, metadata)
- SeatBlock (ID, Location_FK, metadata)
- Seat (ID , SeatBlockID_FK, metadata)
- SeatPricing (ID, Seat_FK [or SeatBlock_FK if pricing is done by block], ShowTime_FK, metadata)
- SeatAssignment (ID, SeatPricing_FK, Seat_FK [if seat pricing is done by block], metadata)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.but if i have Block A for concert #1 and another Block A for concert #2 how can i seprate them?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have different blocks for different concerts, unless you are physically rearranging your seats.  The blocks have nothing to do with the concert; they are only related to a concert when someone has their butt in a seat in that block at a specific concert.  I think you are trying to link the static information and the dynamic information too soon in your hierarchy.

Comment: What is the definition of SeatBlock? Is the the physical seat arrangement driven by SeatID, or is it a virtual representation of pricing tiers that could vary by concert? This isn't clear. In the latter case, SeatBlock would be driven by Concert or Showtime. But do you really expect the SeatValue to vary by Showtime for a given Concert?

Comment: @JAGAnalyst, My definition is based off physical location; I think OP was trying to combine physical location with pricing properties, which really needs to be normalized away.

Comment: SeatBlock , contains some seats and it's not change with for concerts.But SeatValue Chages for every Concerts or Showtimes.For example Adele Concert hold in Royal Albert Hall,the location and SeatBlocks are not changes but the prices changes from another concert.

Comment: @samangholami I have updated my answer to break it down further for you.

Comment: Make relation between Showtime and Seat table in SeatAssignment doesn't make Circular reference?

Comment: @samangholami no they are only linked in one place; either in the `SeatPricing` table if pricing is determined by block, or `SeatAssignments` if pricing is determined by seat.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy,i make a mistake in Circular reference deffenition,what is it exactly?i googled it but ...

Comment: I assumed you meant where two or more entities were referencing each other in a closed pattern.  Unless you are performing recursive queries, it's usually not a big deal in an RDBMS, but it's a sign that your schema is not properly normalized.

Answer (score 1):

- Theatre exists.
- Concert exists.
- Theatre is divided into seat blocks.
- Seat is a part of a seat block.
- Performance of a concert is scheduled at a theatre.
- Performance has seating for sale.

---

[image]